# Ruby, assert_equal of two arrays of objects

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, assert

I have the following situation. I am trying to write a unit test for an array of objects. The object is defined something like this:

```
class Element
  attr_reader :title, :season, :episode

  def initialize ( name, number )
    @name = name
    @number = number
  end

  def to_s
    number = "%02d" % @number

    result = "Number " << number << " " << @name
    result
  end
end
```

During the test I assert two arrays which both contain three elements, the elements are identical and even the order is identical still I get an error that the assert isn't equal. I guess I am missing something really basic here, whats the catch?

If I compare each element by the to_s method, the assert is correct.. Is that the way it should be done in the first place?

Comment: since learning ruby via EdgeCase Ruby Koans, I've found myself using them continuously as a reference for questions like yours.  you might want to check them out for future reference.  http://rubykoans.com/

Comment: @revdrjrr: Thanks for the link, I heard of them already but never got the chance to find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring a method `==` for your class, with the following code.

```
def ==(other)
  self.to_s == other.to_s
end
```

Sidenote, you might want to refactor your to_s method too, for some concise code.

```
def to_s
  "Number %02d #{@name}" % @number
end
```

Edit:

Numbers already have an `==` method defined (https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/fixnum.rb#L117).

Ruby compares arrays by running an `==` compare on each element of an Array. Here's the implementation of `==` on Arrays, as done in Rubinius (a Ruby implementation written almost completely in Ruby itself) https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/array.rb#L474.

If you leave out various error detections, it basically runs an `==` on all the elements of the array, recursively, and returns true if all of them match.

Comment: Okay it worked thanks, but why do I have to do this in the first place? When I have an array of say numbers (which are objects in themselves again as far as I understand..) I do not have to overwrite the == method.
And thanks for the refactoring hint :)

Comment: @Mark, updated the answer as it was too long to explain in a comment :)